# c++ singleton implementation : pimpl idiom for singletons, pros and cons

Tags: c++, oop, singleton

When implementing singletons in c++, I see two ways to store implementation data :

(A) put all implementation data in the private section and implement class as usual 
(B) "pimpl idiom for singletons" : hide implementation data by placing it to the 'Impl' structure, which  can be defined in the implementation file. Private section contains only a reference to the implementation structure.

Here is a concept code to clarify what I mean by (A) and (B) implementation options :

(A) SingletonClassMembers.hpp :

```
// a lot of includes required by private section
#include "HelperClass1.hpp"
#include "HelperClass2.hpp"
// some includes required by public section
// ...
class SingletonClassMembers {
public:
    static SingletonClassMembers& getInstance();
    // public methods
private:
   SingletonClassMembers ();
   ~SingletonClassMembers();
   SingletonClassMembers (const SingletonClassMembers&); //not implemented
   SingletonClassMembers& operator=(const SingletonClassMembers&); //not implemented
   HelperClass1 mMember1;
   HelperClass2 mMember2; //and so on
```

(A) SingletonClassMembers.cpp :

```
#include "SingletonClassMembers.hpp"
SingletonClassMembers& getInstance() { 
    static SingletonClassMembers sImpl; 
    return sImpl; 
}
```

(B) SingletonHiddenImpl.hpp :

```
// some includes required by public section
// ...
class SingletonHiddenImpl {
public:
    static SingletonHiddenImpl& getInstance();
    // public methods
private:
   SingletonHiddenImpl ();
   ~SingletonHiddenImpl ();
   SingletonHiddenImpl (const SingletonHiddenImpl&); //not implemented
   SingletonHiddenImpl& operator=(const SingletonHiddenImpl&); //not implemented
   struct Impl;
   Impl& mImpl;
};
```

(B) SingletonHiddenImpl.cpp :

```
#include "SingletonHiddenImpl.hpp"
#include "HelperClass1.hpp"
#include "HelperClass2.hpp"
```

struct SingletonHiddenImpl::Impl {
    HelperClass1 member1;
    HelperClass2 member2;
};
static inline SingletonHiddenImpl::Impl& getImpl () {
    static Impl sImpl;
    return sImpl;
}
SingletonHiddenImpl::SingletonHiddenImpl ()
: mImpl (getImpl())
{
}

So, using (B) approach, you can hide implementation details better and (unlike pimpl idiom for ordinary classes) there`s no performance loss. I can`t imagine conditions where (A) approach would be more appropriate

The question is, what are the advantages of storing implementation data as class members (A) ?

Thank you

Comment: 1. Singleton, has been discussed
2. Pimpl ideom, has been discussed. I don't see how this brings any thing new? Your question is answered by the pimpl ideom rationale... and has nothing to with this specific implementation.

Comment: Disagree. When pimpl idiom is discussed in the context of ordinary classes, it has performance drawbacks because you need to use heap. Here, it doesn`t has this drawback and I don`t see any reason why not to use it always. So I asked whether I missed something and why would you expose implementation details by placing implementation data in the private section when you can to hide them without any (from my point of view) drawbacks.

Comment: "Singleton, has been discussed 2. Pimpl ideom, has been discussed." One from me : 3. Bill Clinton was a president. All of these is true, but my question is not about it ;) Implementation is provided to clarify my point, and it seems that you missed it.

Comment: Since in this case the overhead of pimpl is not a problem you have answered your own question.

Comment: From the examples I saw on the web, I figured that using (A) approach to implement singletons is a much more widely used practice. I was quite surprised and decided to ask this question to get the reasons of people who use it.

Comment: Don't use singletons. Then the question of using pimpl is void. ( http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/ ). Seriously, if you'd said that you needed a singleton *once* throughout your career, I *might* be persuaded to believe that it was the right solution. But starting your question with "when implementing singletons" just tells me that you are overusing singletons to a ridiculous degree. Stop right there, and come up with one good reason why you *ever* need a singleton.

Comment: "But starting your question with "when implementing singletons" just tells me that you are overusing singletons to a ridiculous degree." Well, you are wrong. I try to avoid using them, but I think that there are (rare) legal uses for them. Anyway, its off-topic here. BTW : thank you for the link

Comment: Why bother adding implementatin data as private member when you can just define it as static (internal linkage) in you implementation?

Comment: jalf, "why you ever need a singleton" - efficiency, for one. Think embedded software.

Answer (score 1):

Using case A has following benefits:

1. You reduce dependency between classes SingletonClassMembers and SingletonHiddenImpl.
2. You don't need to create configurator pattern in class SingletonClassMembers if you trying avoid restriction on (1) by dependency injection
3. This case is weak, but anyway: it is simple to maintenance single class
4. In multithreading environment you will need to support both class synchronization mechanism, while in single class only single locks is needed.

Comment: You have misunderstood me ;) There`s no dependency between SingletonClassMembers and SingletonHiddenImpl classes at all. They are provided to demonstrate differrent approaches to storing implementation data

Comment: On point 4, the main singleton class is a wrapper for Impl, and presumably only returns it, and given that case, only Impl requires proper synchronized access. In reality, the decision between A and B should be driven by whether you really need to hide the existence of members 1 & 2 - is it commercially sensitive that you have members 1 & 2? As long as your sensitive business logic is hidden in the accessors - do you really care?  If so, B, else why over complicate?

Comment: @konstantin - I get you point and my answer is correct, I'm sorry that used the same names for classes. My point was: in second case you need some solution to implement dependency injection between front-class and impl-class.

Comment: @Nim - very good comment, +1. I just need to make comment: @konstantin has asked: "what are the advantages of storing implementation data as class members (A)" - so I just figures this point. Another thing about multithreading. Singleton in multithread environment should be also safe (to avoid creating 2 instances from different threads simultaneously)

Comment: @Nim - it seems for me that almost everyone will agree that it is better to use forward declarations instead of gratuitous \#includes to reduce compile-time dependencies. I prefer (B) for the same reason

Comment: @Dewfy Sorry, but you didn`t get my point. There`s no impl-class. 'Impl' is just a simple structure that is forward-declared in the header file and defined in implementation file. Therefore it is not possible to use it from the other place and your points don`t apply...

Answer (score 1):

As you only have one instance of your singleton, you can actually move your helpers into the implementation class as "static" there without requiring them to be private inside the header. Of course you don't want to initialise them until you start your class so you would use some kind of smart-pointer, could be auto_ptr here or boost::scoped_ptr, or a pointer with boost::once initialisation (more thread-safe) with deletes in your singleton's destructor.

You can call this model C and probably has the best of both worlds as you completely hide your implementation.

As is the case with any singleton, you need to be extra careful not to throw in your constructor.

Comment: It seems for me that (B) model is exactly the same. What is the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

When considering efficiency with pimpl, it is not the heap that causes overhead, but the indirection (done by delegation).  This delegation typically isn't optimized out (at least not at the time I was considering this ;-)), so there is not a big gain apart from the startup (1 time) penalty for creating the impl. (BTW, I didn't see any delegation functions in your example)

So I don't see that much difference in using pimpl in normal classes or in singletons.  I think in both case, using pimpl for classes with limited interface and heavy implementation, it makes sense.

Comment: I agree that for this case, allocating 'Impl' on heap is not an issue. However, when objects are continuously created during runtime, this may become an issue too because calling a system call is a pretty expensive operation.